# Inform when variable equal date in future using php

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a question.
Example, now is 31/08/2013, if i have variable in PHP

```
$time=2013/09/01 08:10:00
```

i want to at this time, (08:10, 1/9/2013) will have an information to user, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check if the current date is equal to it

```
if( date(Y/m/d h:i:s) >= $time) {
    echo 'SURPRISE TUDAY IZ YUR BIRTDAY ';
}
```

Comment: sr, but when i vote for your answer, it request that i must have 15 reputation :(, and i can't to vote

Comment: you dont has to do that you can just click the little check on ze bottom

Comment: You might want `date() >= $time` because what is shown here will only work if the current time is exactly the time shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $strCDay = date('Y/m/d h:i:s');
    $strFDay = '2013/09/01 08:10:00';
    echo strcmp($strCDay, $strFDay) == 0 ? 'Its your day!' : 'Not your day!';
?>
```

It would be preferable to use string function `strcmp` as both days are strings. The function `strcmp` returns 0 for exact match. This could be used in comparing the timestamps.